# Mysql Get the latest amount of item

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I have here a price list table. What I need to get is the latest amount of item.

Here's my current query. `SELECT item, price, max(date) FROM price;`

Here's what I got with my query.

Results:

```
item    | max(price)  | max(date)
----------------------------------
ballpen |   300       | 2014-12-11
```

Table Structure

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  ID  +    Item   +   Code    +  Price    +   Date     +  
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  1   +  Ballpen  +  itm001   +  300      + 2014-07-29 +
+-------------------------------------------------------+
+  2   +  Ballpen  +  itm001   +  701      + 2013-08-29 +   
+-------------------------------------------------------+
+  3   +  Ballpen  +  itm001   +  700      + 2014-12-11 +
+-------------------------------------------------------+
+  4   +  Pencil   +  itm002   +  250      + 2014-12-11 +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Expected Output

```
item    | max(price)  | max(date)
----------------------------------
ballpen |   700       | 2014-12-11
Pencil  |   250       | 2014-12-11
```

Any help will appreciate.

Comment: @EndeNeu Okay, but it has the same result.

Comment: Yes sorry, you made an edit, before it was not so clear.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want the highest price on the most recent date?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Nope, I want the current price of an item.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Mr. Potter, any help please?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  item,
  price, 
  `date`
FROM price
ORDER BY `date` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5621/4/0), also note that `date` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Sorry but to make it clear. I need the current/latest price of item  'ballpen'.

Comment: I make an update. What I need to get is like in my expected output.

Comment: Two things, first the date returned by your query is not in the structure you showed in your question (2014-09-08 is not in the dataset), second, is your date field a date column or a varchar?

Comment: @edneNeu Sorry, I changed the field date to current_date. And (2014-08-09) is the current date right now. So it means current_date is also a reserve keyword? So I changed it again into 'dates' and it gets the right date. But the price wasn't.

Comment: I made an edit and added an SQL fiddle.

Comment: the expected output was right. But the problem is the LIMIT 1. If I use LIMIT, how about my other item if I LIMIT to show only 1?

Comment: Then you want what Barmar put in as a similar question, from your question it was not clear.